# Рабочая ли архитектуры БД?

Tags: база-данных

**Буде ли работать реляционная база данных сконструированная по вот такой схеме?**

[image: Схема базы данных]

*Описание:* Есть пользователи сервиса(Person) которые могут делать заказы(Order) на проведение работ(WorkByOrder) по цене (Prices) у конкретной организации(Organization); 
Также пользователи(Person) могут оценить(Rating) эти организации(Organization).
Беспокоит тот момент что в схеме есть "петли".

Буде ли работать база по такой схеме? или лучше это разбить на 2 части? Как лучше реализовать такую задачу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала стоит разобраться, что такое "петли", которых следует избегать. Вы должно быть имеете ввиду перекрёстные ссылки между двумя таблицами, когда для создания таблицы **B** нужна таблица **A** (в таблице **B** есть внешний ключ из таблицы **A**), а для создания таблицы **A** нужна таблица **B** (в таблице **A** есть внешний ключ из таблицы **B**). В такой ситуации ни одну из таблиц невозможно создать первой из-за ограничений целостности СУБД. И, что более важно, это нарушает реляционную модель данных. В более сложном случае таблицы могут быть связаны не напрямую, а через цепочку других таблиц. В Вашей схеме таких перекрёстных связей между таблицами нет. Я немного перерисовал Вашу схему. Для наглядности связи типа "один ко многим" я заменил на стрелки, показывающие порядок создания таблиц (и внесения в них записей). Зависимые таблицы я расположил на схеме ниже, чем те таблицы, от которых они зависят. Получилось что-то вроде ориентированного графа. Думаю, так нагляднее.
[image: схема]